# Python Fire module not showing COMMANDS in `-h`

Tags: python, oop, command-line-interface, python-fire

I am using the python `Fire` module with an abstract parent class and a child class. Not all functions are abstract, some functions do not need to be replicated for each child:

### parent class

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Foo(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        # some initialisations

    @abstractmethod
    def fun1(self, file=None):
       # Some calls

    def fun2(self):
       # Non abastract func... Some calls
```

### child class (test.py)

```
import fire
from foo import Foo

class Child(Foo)
     def __init__(self, val=None):
        super().__init__(val)
        # some initialisations

     def fun1(file='path/to/file')
        # do some stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(Child)
```

when I run python CLI with `python -m test --help` I do not get any `COMMANDS` i.e. Fire is not recognising any functions to run. However it is recognising the parent global variables and `init` flags to set so why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

try passing it the instantiated object instead [like they do here](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md#version-3-firefireobject)

```
fire.Fire(Child())
```

Comment: What if I have init-arguments?